# How to select a sub collection available in a list of collection

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, .net-3.5, windows-ce

The following is my class structure

```
   public class ProductInfo
         Dim productName As string 
      Dim productCode As string 
      Dim Locations As List(of String)
   End Class
```

Getting product List

```
Dim listProd As List(of ProductInfo)= entityProvider.GetProducts();
```

My collection contains 50 products and each product will have some number of locations. How can I query this collection using Linq to get distinct sub collection (all `Locations` for all the product, but distinct. Because 2 product can be seen in same location)

I am using **.NET 3.5 CE**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` to get all locations and `Distinct` to make them distinct:

```
Dim distinctLocations = entityProvider.GetProducts().
    SelectMany(Function(p) p.Locations).
    Distinct()
```